# Why vGPU (Tesla K80) on Google cloud slower than GTX940M on T460P

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gpu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a question about the vGPU (Tesla K80) on the VM of Google cloud.

My laptop is Lenovo T460P equiped with below spec:

- CPU: intel i7-6700HQ
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: nVIDIA GTX 940M (CUDA Cores: 348)
- OS: Windiws 10 Pro 64bit
- OpenCV: ver3.2.0 with CUDA 8.0 support (I downloaded from http://jamesbowley.co.uk/downloads/)

The VM I created in Google Cloud contains the below spec:

- CPU: vCPU x 2
- RAM: 4GB
- HDD: 25GB
- GPU: vGPU (Tesla K80) x 1  (CUDA Cores 4992)
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit
- CUDA Driver: I follow the install procedure from this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus
- OpenCV: ver 3.2.0 (compile parameters:
- - cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D CUDA_GENERATION=Auto -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_NVCUVID=1 -D WITH_CUFFT=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=ON -D WITH_IPP=ON )

I use opencv to train LBP cascade with 160 positive images and 800 negative images.
I use the same positive and negative samples on both above environments
Below is the parameters of opencv_createsamples and opencv_traincascade:

> opencv_createsamples -info data/positive_images/positives.txt -vec data/positive_images/positives.vec -w 32 -h 32
>
> opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec data/positive_images/positives.vec  -bg data/negative_images/negatives.txt -mode BASIC -featureType LBP  -numPos 160 -numNeg 800 -minHitRate 0.998 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.05 -w 32 -h 32 -numStages 10

However, I found that my laptop took 5 minutes around to finish the training. and the vm of Google cloud took over 20 minutes and was still in TRAINING 8-stage.

[image: opencv_traincascade on Google cloud vm with Tesla K80]

[image: nvidia-smi on Google cloud vm]

What's the matter with the vm of Google cloud ?
I thought that the vm of Google cloud should have computed faster than that of my laptop because the vm has a Tesla K80. But it actually is far slow than my laptop.

Did I miss something or do something wrong on the vm of Google cloud ?

Thanks for help.