# Slower training on Google Cloud Tesla K80 than on local laptop machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gpu

Similar unanswered question here: [Why vGPU (Tesla K80) on Google cloud slower than GTX940M on T460P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939323/why-vgpu-tesla-k80-on-google-cloud-slower-than-gtx940m-on-t460p)

I developed a segmentation network on my laptop, which has an nvidia GTX 1070 8GB. Each epoch takes ~4 minutes for training.

I decided to shift my training to google cloud, and spun up a 'Deep Learning VM' instance with 8 vCPUs and 1 Tesla K80 GPU. The training is significantly slower on Google, with each epoch taking ~12 minutes. I would expect it to be the same speed, if not faster. Any ideas why this is happening, or is a cloud instance usually slower than a GPU laptop? The environment is exactly the same except my laptop was running Python 3.6 and the cloud instance is python 3.5, but I don't expect this to be the reason for the speed difference.

Comment: As you know, when you work with Tensor Cores enabled on NVIDIA GPUs, you would [reduce](https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning) AI training times. In this case, as you chosen the Tesla K80 GPU, seems that the performance issue is related to the Tensor cores within the GPU (this model has no Tensor cores). You should consider this [table](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#gpu_comparison_chart) and choose the GPU according to your workload type to possibly optimice the performance over your training job.